# how to convert powerpoint note text to speech with vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint, text-to-speech

I want to write a VBA macro that converts the note text to speech using the native windows speech capability.  
Anyone done this before?  
Any tips how to start and proceed?  
In the end I will need to provide different EU languages for conversion.  
Thanks John.

Comment: There's no direct access to this from PPT itself, but you can automate Excel's text to speech engine from within PowerPoint.  You can find examples via a web search on terms like "excel text to speech vba" (w/o the quote marks)

Comment: I've done this in a prototype add-in with VBA in PowerPoint although it does use a reference to the Microsoft Speech Object Library. I managed to get it to read slide notes and even use a custom voice. I'll dig out some code and reply back later.

Answer (score 1):

Right, as mentioned above, add a reference in your project to Microsoft Speech Object Library.

Then this function will set you on the right path:

```
Function SpeakThis(myPhrase As String)
  Dim oSpeaker As New SpeechLib.SpVoice

  ' Set speech properties
  oSpeaker.Volume = 100 ' percent
  oSpeaker.Rate = 1 ' multiplier
  oSpeaker.SynchronousSpeakTimeout = 1
  oSpeaker.AlertBoundary = SVEWordBoundary

  If Not myPhrase = "" Then oSpeaker.Speak myPhrase, SVSFDefault
End Function
```

Then call this:

```
SpeakThis "Hello, my name is Jamie and I love VBA!"
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie, I'll try it after my holiday that starts tomorrow.   <br/>Hope you do not think I'll forget!

Comment: Hi Jamie, should I provide a link to the SpeechLib.SpVoice somewhere? I am getting an error that the User defined type was not specified. Any clues? Thx John

Comment: @JamieGarroch  could  you advice on the above problem, I am also facing the same issue