# Text to Speech |VBA| Power Point

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, sapi

I am new to the world of VBA, and I am trying to execute the code that will convert text to speech in the PowerPoint. It seems that I need to add the XLS speech libraries to PPT. Does any one know how to add the speech libraries to PowerPoint. So that the I can execute the TTS in PowerPoint.

I tried to find the library that is used by Excel by going to the folder that is mentioned in the Tool>>

The code that I am trying to execute 
[how to convert powerpoint note text to speech with vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154652/how-to-convert-powerpoint-note-text-to-speech-with-vba/31167309#31167309?newreg=a52b820feaf24d838cf9bdc12c33df02)

The following link provides one solution about late binding, this code also gives error
[how to convert powerpoint note text to speech with vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154652/how-to-convert-powerpoint-note-text-to-speech-with-vba)
I found the following information but I am not able to bind the Excel methods to PowerPoint library.

Back story:

My Professor wants to to automate the process by which we synchronize the bullet point on the power point slide with the bookmarks on the audio file. If we can create audio bookmark tags that follow a naming convention for example BM__ then the the VB script could link/synchronize the audio bookmark to the Bullet point on Slide x or  y or  x.

Then this PPT can be converted to the slide show and posted on a learning management system.

---

Research on different forums pointed to the fact the PPT can covert the text to speech by binding objects in Excel. (Excel the text to speech will execute fine)

I have attached a visio of the high level flow.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jamie mentioned in the article you linked to, you need to set a reference to the Microsoft Speech Object Library.

In the VBA IDE, choose Tools | References
Scroll down to Microsoft Speech Object Library, put a check next to it then click OK.

I copy/pasted Jamie's code into PPT, added the reference as above and it worked perfectly (though I must admit telling the PC to say something nice about Jamie rather than whatever his example showed).

Comment: Steve, I followed the steps mentioned by you. But when I try to execute the code, i get compile error at oSpeaker. Volume ---> 'Method or data member not found'

Comment: Hello Steve, My computer has two object libraries (sapi.dll) one was in C:\Windows\System32\Speech_OneCore\Common  and the other one was in C:\Windows\System32\Speech\Common. After I set the reference to the second library the code functionswell. Thank you very much for the direction.

Comment: Odd problem I'd imagine, but thanks for reporting the solution.